# Why does template binded converter not work?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, controltemplate

I have control template with a `Border`. I want to bind its background by template binding, but I also need to create an `x:Name` property for the `SolidColorBrush`. So I create a simple converter from `Brush` to `Color`, but it doesn't work and I don't understand why.

My XAML:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button" x:Key="appBtns">
    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <local:ColorConverter x:Key="ColorConverter"/>
    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
    <Border x:Name="BackRect" CornerRadius="15" BorderThickness="0" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}">
        <Border.Background >
            <SolidColorBrush x:Name="BackRectColor" Color="{TemplateBinding Background, Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}}"/>
        </Border.Background>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

My converter:

```
public class ColorConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((SolidColorBrush)value).Color;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`TemplateBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/templatebinding-markup-extension?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) markup extension is known to be very limited in some scenarios. However, you can simply use a regular binding with a [`RelativeSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) of [`TemplatedParent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.relativesource.templatedparent?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) instead.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Name="BackRectColor" Color="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}}"/>
```

In fact, if you always use a `SolidColorBrush`, you do not even need a converter. Just specify the `Color` property of the `Background` `SolidColorBrush` as property path. It is resolved at runtime.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button" x:Key="appBtns">
   <Border x:Name="BackRect" CornerRadius="15" BorderThickness="0" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}">
      <Border.Background >
         <SolidColorBrush x:Name="BackRectColor" Color="{Binding Background.Color, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
      </Border.Background>
   </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```